# Keep Ask Question button to the right on smaller screens

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, responsive-design

On smaller screens, the 'Ask Question' button is now sandwiched *between* the question title and the statistics. This is rather illogical, as it will move you *away* from the question page. Can we move it somewhere to the right? The bar with the logo might work (though its colors would need to be adjusted, and there will be less room for wide logo 's like the one on Science Fiction & Fantasy. Alternatively, keep it in the current bar but at the bottom right. And if it stays where it is, please increase the bottom padding.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332526/295232), in a new build, the Ask Question button is (almost) back where it belongs.

[image]