# “Ask Question” button shoved to the right in responsive mobile on some posts

Tags: bug, responsive-design

Looking at the sites today, I noticed a glitch on the responsive mobile design (iPhone 7 running Safari).

On Meta:

[image: Ask Question is pushed to the right, only “Ask” is on-screen]

On a Stack Overflow Team:

[image: Same thing]

Apparently this sometimes happens when there’s a long word in the titles of posts. I’ve found a lot of examples on Charcoal’s Stack Overflow Team, one on Meta, but none on Science Fiction, so it seems to not affect some sites.

Comment: Same problem on Android 7 with latest Chrome Stable.

Comment: Well, at least it's [better than the previous iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331466/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel that one has returned.

Comment: This was fixed for very small widths, but still occurs for widths where the CSS hasn't opted to cut out the left menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt5yf.png

Comment: @animuson changing the window size slowly on Firefox (Mac) doesn't reproduce that.